# Which sorting algorithm should I use for a list with a lot of replications?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to sort an array of 1 million integers. What would be the best algorithm to use knowing that the universe of the array's integers are from 1 to 100? Note that this means that there are a lot of items replicated. Furthermore, the array is randomly distributed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create an array of 100 elements (with one for each possible value) and simply count how many there are of each. Running time: `O(n)`, with each element of the original array accessed only once, so you're unlikely to find a faster one. :)

Or to give it its proper name, use a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: Or in other words - do a counting sort :-)

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Thanks, I didn't even realise this had a name.